# Open document in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

So our organization just moved to SharePoint Online. We have a few sites where

- when you click on a document in the library it is opening a blank IE page.
- But if you revert back to classic mode the documents open.

Does anyone know how to get the document to open in the new view?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to use another browser like chrome to open a document in a modern experience? Maybe it's a compatibility issue!

Comment: Any update on this issue? Can you reproduce this issue with another user account? See a similar post here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-documents-opening-blank/7e660fd0-78d7-495e-aca3-9d214e0ed778?auth=1

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a browser issue. Refer to [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/which-browsers-work-with-office-for-the-web-ad1303e0-a318-47aa-b409-d3a5eb44e452) and make sure you are using a supported version of the browser. In my experience, Internet Explorer should be avoided for most SharePoint versions.